# Xcode 10 not symbolicating crash log

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode10, symbolicatecrash

I have couple of crashes on startup of app and there are no code changes made since it was last installed by Xcode. When I open device logs, Xcode is not fully symbolicating crash, particularly the place where it crashed. Why is it so and how do I get the fully symbolicated crash log? The crash is unfortunately not reproducible in direct debugging session.

```
  Date/Time:           2018-12-01 12:30:38.3874 +0400
  Launch Time:         2018-12-01 12:30:36.0854 +0400
  OS Version:          iPhone OS 12.1 (16B92)
  Baseband Version:    2.01.07
  Report Version:      104

  Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
  Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000101abe1a4
  Termination Signal: Trace/BPT trap: 5
  Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0x5
  Terminating Process: exc handler [43684]
  Triggered by Thread:  0

  Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
  Thread 0 Crashed:
   0   libswiftCore.dylib               0x0000000101abe1a4 0x1018cc000 + 2040228
   1   libswiftCore.dylib               0x0000000101abe1a4 0x1018cc000 + 2040228
   2   libswiftCore.dylib               0x0000000101925db8 0x1018cc000 + 368056
   3   MyApp-Swift                  0x0000000100e69880 0x100d64000 + 1071232
   4   MyApp-Swift                  0x0000000100dfbd00 0x100d64000 + 621824
   5   MyApp-Swift                  0x0000000100dfbdb8 0x100d64000 + 622008
   6   UIKitCore                        0x00000001c29da768 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 96
   7   UIKitCore                        0x00000001c24686d0 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 80
   8   UIKitCore                        0x00000001c24689f0 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 440
   9   UIKitCore                        0x00000001c24679f0 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 568
   10  UIKitCore                        0x00000001c2a1418c -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 2472
   11  UIKitCore                        0x00000001c2a153f0 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 3156
   12  UIKitCore                        0x00000001c29f46ec -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 340
   13  UIKitCore                        0x00000001c2ac057c __dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 1620
   14  UIKitCore                        0x00000001c2ac2f74 __handleEventQueueInternal + 4740
   15  UIKitCore                        0x00000001c2abba64 __handleHIDEventFetcherDrain + 152
   16  CoreFoundation                   0x00000001958ac1cc __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
   17  CoreFoundation                   0x00000001958ac14c __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 88
   18  CoreFoundation                   0x00000001958aba30 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 176
   19  CoreFoundation                   0x00000001958a68fc __CFRunLoopRun + 1040
   20  CoreFoundation                   0x00000001958a61cc CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
   21  GraphicsServices                 0x0000000197b1d584 GSEventRunModal + 100
   22  UIKitCore                        0x00000001c29d9054 UIApplicationMain + 212
   23  MyApp-Swift                  0x0000000100f48dec 0x100d64000 + 1986028
   24  libdyld.dylib                    0x0000000195366bb4 start + 4
```

Comment: Typically you use the atos command line tool to symbolicate the crash report. Apple has an superb guide on this here https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/diagnosing_issues_using_crash_reports_and_device_logs/adding_identifiable_symbol_names_to_a_crash_report